# How to Bind HandsonTables in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, handsontable

I am developing a web application using MVC4.  and I have HandsOnTable in UI.  I tried to bind the data using json, but cant. and doesn't tell shows error.  Here is code snippet

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Customer/GetSpreadSheetGrid",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { customerId: customerID }
        })
            .success(function (result) {
    var vSpreadSheet = document.getElementById("SpreadSheetgrid");
        $("#SpreadSheetgrid").handsontable("loadData", result);
    })
    .fail(function (r, o) {
        alert("Failed : " + r.responseText);
    });
    }
```

and here is my controller method

```
public JsonResult GetSpreadSheetGrid(int customerId)
    {
IEnumerable<tblCustomerSpreadsheetInfo> resResult = null;
// Calling SP
resResult = _customer.GetCustomerCustomInfoByCustomerID(customerId);
return Json(resResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Whats the mistake in this code.

Comment: which is failing here.. ajax or handsontable?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="dataTable" class="dataTable"></div>    
$("#dataTable").handsontable({
       rows: 6,
       cols: 8,
       contextMenu: true,
       colHeaders: true
    });
    var url = "/Home/GridData";
    $.get(url, null, function (data) {
    $("#dataTable").handsontable("loadData", data);
    strong text});
```

This is the method in HomeController

```
public JsonResult GridData()
        {
            var jsonData = new[]
                         {
                             new[] {"1", "4", "Is this a good question?"},
                             new[] {"2", "5", "Yes."},
                             new[] {"3", "6", "It is!"}
                        };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I achieved binding controller method to a handsontable with this code.
But i am really struggling getting data and passing it as string[][] to a controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your jquery ajax as follows(keep a debugger inside both success and failure functions. using IE and Visual Studio debug it. There you can see errors if any.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Customer/GetSpreadSheetGrid",
        type: "GET",
        data: { customerId: customerID },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (_results) {
             debugger;
            var vSpreadSheet = document.getElementById("SpreadSheetgrid");
            $("#SpreadSheetgrid").handsontable("loadData", result);
        },
        error: function (_results, status) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Dumb question: Using ASP.NET MVC, is the original rendering of the table  on the first web page hit normally rendered by a view? I understand that subsequent paging is done using an ajax call that returns JSON but not having much experience in web dev, I can't picture fully how it works. Would the server dynamically build the first page with the json data embedded in dynamically created javascript? I'm thinking not. I'm wondering how we get that first data bind  when we initiatlize the table as a handsontable. Sorry for my ignorance